# I can't run my csh-script in Ubuntu

Tags: scripts, csh

I write sch-script (cm2.csh) and trying to run in Ubintu (c shell installed), but receive error like:

```
bash: ./cm2.csh: /bin/csh/: bad interpreter: Not a directory
```

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set REGION = 75.85/76.5/41.37/41.7
set AXIS = f3ma3mWSne
set SIZE = M26c
set grdfile = Naryn.grd
set psfile = Naryn.ps

set cptfile = color.cpt
makecpt -Cglobe -Z > $cptfile

grdimage $grdfile -R$REGION -J$SIZE -C$cptfile -U -K > $psfile
grdcontour $grdfile -R$REGION -J$SIZE -C50 -A150 -K -O >> $psfile
pscoast -R$REGION -J$SIZE -B$AXIS -Df -W2,150 -O -K >> $psfile
psmeca Hindukush-psmeca.cmt -R$REGION -J$SIZE -Sm0.5c/-2 -Zdepth.cpt -O -K >> $psfile
#grdcontour $grdfile -J$SIZE -C25 -A50+s10 -B1g30m -O -K >> $psfile

pstext -R -JM -O -K <<PROF2>> $psfile
75.98 41.43 18 0 1 LT Naryn
PROF2

psxy -R -JM -St0.5c -G255/0/0 -W1 -P -O <<TRE>> $psfile
75.97 41.426
TRE
```

What I should do?

Comment: We can't help you debug a script you don't share with us! It looks like you have a malformed shebang line, most probably `#!/bin/csh/` instead of `#!/bin/csh` but we can't be sure since you haven't shown your code.

Comment: How do you execute your script? Do you run `./cm2.csh`? Or `csh cm2.csh`? Something else? The script you show should work (and does work, I just tested). Are you _sure_ that's the script you're using?

Comment: I use ./cm2.csh

Comment: do you know about gmt?

Comment: What works? Is your issue resolved? Did you originally have `#!/bin/csh/`?

Comment: might you please help on command line in Ubuntu?
In my case the command line in the terminal starts from: #
to me usual: name@name: ~$
How I can switch to usual case?

Comment: You are logged in as root. Run `exit` or press Ctrl+D and then open a new terminal.

Comment: No I'm not login as SU (root), it's always when I start working newly

Comment: What works? Is your issue resolved? Did you originally have #!/bin/csh/? – terdon♦ Sep 26 at 9:33


Yes, you are right. Originally was with slash.

Comment: when will happen in a terminal - %?

Comment: If you have a new question, please [post it separately](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).